# WSE 3.0 crashes when ClearHeaders is called

Tags: c#, web-services, wse3.0

I'm developing a client-server application in c# using WSE web-service. One of the things that the user can do is send jpg images to the server for backup via the web-service. Recently strange errors have occurred. This does not happen for all users, just a few. On the client side the exception is a

```
System.Net.WebException Exception message: The operation has timed out
```

and on the server the following warning is found in the event viewer:

```
Exception information:      
Exception type: HttpException
Exception message: Server cannot clear headers after HTTP headers have been sent.
Request information
Request URL: MyUrl/Service.asmx
Request path: /MyWebService/Service.asmx
User host address: -------
User:
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type:
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Thread information:
Thread ID: 7
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace: at System.Web.HttpResponse.ClearHeaders()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.WriteException(Exception e, Stream outputStream)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
```

Does anyone have an idea where this error can come from? I have already tried to raise the "maxRequestLength" in web.config to 16Mb but this doesn't fix it.

Regards
/Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WSE because you have no choice? That's really the only reason to use it, as it's quite obsolete. Are you unable to use WCF?

Comment: its unfortunately a legacy thing. At least it is nothing a can change right now...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing. While I was looking into the problem, I came upon this question. I just wanted to share what I've found so far.

What I'm finding on the net is pretty simple. By increasing the maxRequestLength (to a sane amount) in your system.web section of the web.config file you can fix this problem.

I suppose, having done no more research than this, is that your default settings for maxRequestLength will not handle the size of the request being presented when one of your users send a larger JPG to be backed up in your system via your WSE web service.

You may wish to add time to your executionTimeout setting as well.